# How to find out number of bits enabled : bits handling

Tags: c

This was asked in one of the interview I gave. I couldn't answer this properly.

I want to find out how many bits are enabled based on a number.

Suppose , if the number is 2 , I should return 3.
          if the number is 3 , I should return 7

```
8 4 2 1 

    1 1 

8 4 2 1

  1 1 1
```

Is there any easy way of doing it?

Comment: I do not see what you mean by "enabled", such that 2 ==> 3 and 3 ==> 7.  Please elaborate on your examples.  What if the number is 5?  Is that 3 bits? or 2?

Comment: The problem is that your question title is "find out number of bits enabled", but the answers `3` and `7` are not "number of bits". Perhaps you meant "find out number **if** bits enabled" instead?

Comment: The text of the question doesn't match the examples. Do you want the numeric value based on the number of least significant bits set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is: subtract 1 from the corresponding power of 2, like this:

```
int allBitsSet = (1U << n) - 1;
```

The expression `(1U << n) - 1` computes the value of `2` to the power of `n`, which always has this form in binary:

```
1000...00
```

i.e. one followed by `n` zeros. When you subtract `1` from a number of that form, you "borrow" from the bit that is set to `1` making it zero, and flip the remaining bits to `1`.

You can visualize this by solving an analogous problem in decimal system: "make a number that has `n` nines". The solution is the same, except now you need to use 10 instead of 2.